# How to extract some particular values in the entire row in ipython notebook

Tags: python, dataframe

S.No   Name    city

1     a      Nairobi

2     b      rome

3     c      Nairobi

Code:

Info_data.at[City = [Nairobi]]

Error:

Info_data.at[City = [Nairobi]]
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Output:

Sno Name     City

1    a     Nairobi

3    c     Nairobi

Answer (score 0):

Using `pandas`:

```py
nairobi = df[df["City"] == "Nairobi"]
```

Comment: Yup, that worked thank you @Alex